# combination of two sequences that converges to the derivative of function f.

Tags: real-analysis

I saw the following statement somewhere in the other post: Given $f$ is differentiable at $x$. Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two sequences that converges to $x$ and $x_n > y_n$ for all $n$. Then $\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}$ converges to $f'(x)$. This result seems to be intuitive but I couldn't find a way to formally prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If $y_n<x<x_n$ then $\frac {f(x_n)-f(y_n)} {x_n-y_n} -f'(x)= [\frac {f(x_n)-f(x)} {x_n-x}-f'(x)] \frac {x_n-x} {x_n-y_n} +[\frac {f(x)-f(y_n)} {x-y_n}-f'(x)] \frac {x-y_n} {x_n-y_n}$ and similar identities hold when $x<y_n<x_n$ and when $y_n<x_n<x$. from these identities it is easy to see that the left side tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this construction is really interesting. However since both (xn-x) and (xn-yn) tends to 0, is it possible that their quotient might diverge to infinity?

Comment: @ZhengWu The quantities within [.] can be made $\epsilon$ and then you will get $\frac {x_n-x} {x_n-y_n} +\frac {x-y_n} {x_n-y_n} =1$. It doesn't matter what happens to $\frac {x_n-x} {x_n-y_n}$ and $\frac {x-y_n} {x_n-y_n} $ individually.